# Why is my list sometimes including false references in my PostgreSQL view?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a problem on this view :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.v_izae_unites_foncieres_13
AS SELECT row_number() OVER () AS ogc_fid,
    foo.code_insee,
    foo.nompro,
    foo.adr_prop,
    foo.cp_prop,
    foo.ville_prop,
    foo.wkb_geometry,
    round(st_area(foo.wkb_geometry)::integer::numeric, 0) AS surface,
    concat(zae.numero_zae, '-', row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY zae.numero_zae ORDER BY zae.ogc_fid)) AS code,
    foo.refparc_liste,
    foo.numero_zae
   FROM ( SELECT faa.code_insee,
            faa.nompro,
            faa.adr_prop,
            faa.cp_prop,
            faa.ville_prop,
            faa.numero_zae,
            (st_dump(st_union(faa.wkb_geometry))).geom::geometry(Polygon,2154) AS wkb_geometry,
            array_agg(faa.refparc) AS refparc_liste
           FROM ( SELECT parcelles.ogc_fid,
                    parcelles.wkb_geometry,
                    parcelles.code_insee,
                    parcelles.nompro,
                    parcelles.adr_prop,
                    parcelles.cp_prop,
                    parcelles.ville_prop,
                    parcelles.refparc,
                    parcelles.numero_zae
                   FROM zae zae_1
                     JOIN LATERAL ( SELECT parcelles_ozae.ogc_fid,
                            parcelles_ozae.wkb_geometry,
                            parcelles_ozae.code_insee,
                            parcelles_ozae.nompro,
                            parcelles_ozae.adr_prop,
                            parcelles_ozae.cp_prop,
                            parcelles_ozae.ville_prop,
                            parcelles_ozae.refparc,
                            parcelles_ozae.numero_zae
                           FROM parcelles_ozae
                          WHERE st_contains(zae_1.wkb_geometry, st_pointonsurface(parcelles_ozae.wkb_geometry))) parcelles ON true) faa
          GROUP BY faa.nompro, faa.code_insee, faa.adr_prop, faa.cp_prop, faa.ville_prop, faa.numero_zae) foo
     JOIN zae ON foo.numero_zae::text = zae.numero_zae::text;
```

The objective of this view is to get data named 'unites_foncieres' made from entites in the table 'parcelles_ozae'.

The view works, but I have issues with the refparc_liste.

The refparc_liste is an aggregation of all the refparc oh the parcelles_ozae that constitute the unites_foncieres (the data created with the view).

Sometimes, my refparc_liste has several refparc but only one parcelles_ozae constitue the unites_foncieres.
I noticed this happened only when the parcelles_ozae have the same
code_insee, nom_pro, adr_prop, cp_prop and ville_prop.

So when the owner is the same (pro/prop suffix means owner) even if the parcelles_ozae are not next each other : the refparc_list will be constituted of all the refparc of other parcelles_ozae.

For example, on the screenshots : there is only one parcelles_ozae
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XhPw.png

(refparc : BX0095) constituting the unites_foncieres but the refparc_liste references several refparc :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi9JP.png

The good one is here : BX0095 but they are other ones that don't constitute the unites_foncieres.

Do you have a solution ? Thank you !

Someone provided me this solution :

Fields asked and returned by the DB when opening the attribute table, getting feature information, displaying a feature geometry etc are not always the same, and consequently the DB can (and will) execute the query differently, returning rows in different order.

Because the view assigns an ID based on the row number, but without ordering ALL results first, it is possible that the same ID gets assigned to different features on different calls. You click on feature #1, the ID is sent to the DB to get all fields values, but the now feature #1 is a totally different feature.

Change

`SELECT row_number() OVER () AS ogc_fid,`

for a version setting a definitive order between all results

`SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY layer1.id, layer2.id, layer3.id) AS ogc_fid,`

But I don't get it.

Comment: You make a `JOIN` with `ON true` as the criterion. Don't you think it may put together records that have no relation with each other? As to what you should have done instead (or even whether this is what is causing your issue), without a description of your schema + sample data, there is nothing we can do. Please see [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).